# JavaFX TreeTableView Disclosure Node arrow stops row selection

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX application using TreeTableViews using JFX8.

Is there a way to stop TreeTableViews from intercepting mouse-clicks in the region of the Disclosure Node arrow even when the row is a leaf (ie has no children) and thereby has no Disclosure Node expand arrow? The current behaviour seems to be to intercept these mouse-clicks in the far-left of the Row, though I think users would expect the row to be selected as there is no disclosure node.

[image: sammple image]

See below example...

```
public class TestTreeTableViewApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        anchorPane.setPrefWidth(600);
        anchorPane.setPrefHeight(600);

        TreeTableView<String> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>();
        TreeTableColumn<String, String> primaryColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Col1");
        primaryColumn.setPrefWidth(200);

        treeTableView.getColumns().add(primaryColumn);
        //Just to show some data in the column for test purposes...
        primaryColumn.setCellValueFactory(call -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(call.getValue().getValue()));

        treeTableView.setRoot(new TreeItem<>("Root"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            TreeItem<String> newChild = new TreeItem<>("1st Tier Test " + i);
            treeTableView.getRoot().getChildren().add(newChild);
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                TreeItem<String> newChild2 = new TreeItem<>("2nd Tier Test " + i);
                newChild.getChildren().add(newChild2);
            }
        }

        anchorPane.getChildren().add(treeTableView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane, 600, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm .. feels like a bug (same in current fx, so was/is there since ages), leaf children of the root behave as expected - please report so that's not forgotten :)

Comment: definitely a bug: happens after the disclosurenode (that's the expansion icon) had been added at least once by the rowSkin (working if initially expanded: expand the first child before showing and see that selection happens on click into the region). Underlying reason is smeared responsibility of that icon: it is a child of the row (created by treeTableViewSkin!), added and layout-managed by TreeTableRowSkin - but the mouseHandling done by TreeTableCellBehavior in its handleDisclosureNode. Which should check for the node's visibility .. but doesn't .. what a mess ...

Comment: OK thanks, good to know its not me! Will report it.

Comment: reported https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8253597 and taken. A fix will not necessarily be backported to fx8, but maybe you can hack your environment a bit (pre-9 it was possible to go dirty with behaviors, nowadays there is no way to override their base mouse hooks ..)

Comment: Thanks very much @kleopatra I hadn't got around to that, much appreciated.